# upgrading .NET application from MapPoint 2004 to 2009

Tags: c#, .net, upgrade, mappoint

I am in the process of upgrading a Visual Studio 2005 .NET (C#) application from it's integration with MapPoint 2004 to supporting MapPoint 2009.  After a bit of searching and fiddling, I've generated new DLLs using "tldimp" and "aximp" and now have Interop.MapPoint.dll and AxInterop.MapPoint.dll and the namespaces seem to line up to the previous ones, so all the object definitions are available.

However, I have lots of errors telling me that various properties do not exist, even though I go into the Object Browser, and they do seem to exist.

Here is an example (there are dozens of similar errors)...

```
axMappointControl1.ActiveMap.Altitude = 1000;
```

That object initializes fine, as a MapPoint.Map object, which when I browse to in the Object Browser, I go to MapPoint and Map and under Map there are no properties but when I look deeper there is _Map80 and _Map90 and EACH of these has an Altitude property.  Under Map it also lists "Base Types", which has _Map in it which also has all the referenced properties!  Yet, I am getting the error:

```
"MapPoint.Map' does not contain a definition for 'Altitude'
```

Pretty much all the properties of both MapPoint.Map and MapPoint.Toolbars are doing this.  Any ideas?

Thank you!
Joshua

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out.  There was a THIRD DLL file produced, I'm not sure by which generative process.  This one just called **MapPoint.dll** (in addition to AxInterop.MapPoint.dll and Interop.MapPoint.dll) and all three were needed.  Enough fiddling and it worked.  THANKS!